# Почему код не создает бесконечный цикл?

Tags: android, android-handler

В примере из книги HeadFirst Android указан следующий код:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stopwatch);
    runTimer();
    }
    private void runTimer() {
    final TextView timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

 @Override
    public void run() {
    int hours = seconds/3600;
    int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
    int secs = seconds%60;
    String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",
    hours, minutes, secs);
    timeView.setText(time);
    if (running) {
    seconds++;
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
    });
    }
```

Далее в объяснении сказано:

> Вопрос:А разве нельзя просто включить в onCreate() цикл для обновления
>   таймера? Ответ: Нет, метод onCreate() должен завершиться до того, как
>   экран приложения появится перед пользователем. С бесконечным циклом
>   это никогда не произойдет.

Почему код не образует бесконечный цикл, если в конце анонимного класса стоит метод

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
```

который возобновляет выполнение метода Run()?

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный Вами отрывок кода создаст зацикленное обновление таймера раз в секунду (приблизительную секунду при идеальных условиях).

Следующий отрывок из книги:

> Вопрос:А разве нельзя просто включить в onCreate() цикл для обновления
>   таймера? Ответ: Нет, метод onCreate() должен завершиться до того, как
>   экран приложения появится перед пользователем. С бесконечным циклом
>   это никогда не произойдет.

интерпретируется не так, как Вы поняли.

Тут вопрошающий буквально спрашивает:

> А что если обойтись **без** `Handler`-а с его методом `post` и
>   `Runnable`, заменив их на `while` или `for` прямо в методе `onCreate`?

На что автор ему отвечает:

> Убери руки от клавиатуры и иди читай про UI-поток. Если ты так
>   сделаешь, то ты повесишь UI-поток на этапе `onCreate` и никогда не
>   увидишь UI-элементов на экране!